# Assimp : import camera

Tags: import, model, camera, fbx, assimp

I'm using the assimp library to import some FBX model, but I can't find a way to correctly retrieve the camera coordinates!

Does someone has experience with this ?

Here is my code:

```
    // Find the transformation matrix corresponding to the camera node
aiNode* rootNode = _assimpScene->mRootNode;
aiNode* cameraNode = rootNode->FindNode(assimpCamera->mName.data);

aiMatrix4x4 T;
while(cameraNode != rootNode)
{
    T = cameraNode->mTransformation * T;
    cameraNode = cameraNode->mParent;
}

aiMatrix4x4 R = T;
R.a4 = R.b4 = R.c4 = 0.f;
R.d4 = 1.f;

// Transform
aiVector3D from = T * assimpCamera->mPosition;
aiVector3D up = R * assimpCamera->mUp;
aiVector3D lookAt = R * assimpCamera->mLookAt;

// Set up the camera
camera->eyeFrom = luxrays::Point(from.x, from.y, from.z);

lookAt = lookAt.Normalize();
camera->eyeAt = luxrays::Point(from.x + lookAt.x, from.y + lookAt.y, from.z + lookAt.z);

up = up.Normalize();
camera->eyeUp = luxrays::Point(up.x, up.y, up.z);
```

Comment: Please check https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/807

Comment: What kind of issue do you see? For me the code look correct. But when using fbx the dimensions of the model are sometime scaled by 0.01.